# Could not load file or assembly 'system.net, version=2.0.5.0' on VS2015 RC universal when using youtube api

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube

With the code below,

```
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;

var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

I get error

> Could not load file or assembly 'system.net, version=2.0.5.0' on
>   VS2015 RC universal

I tried the old version of youtube and the newest version but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think System.Net is not fully available in Windows universal apps, but the API tries to use it...

Comment: What's API can use it

Comment: How do you mean that? The API is developed for ordinary Windows Applications and not for universal Apps... System.Net is a Desktop Namespace, in universal Apps can't use it.

Comment: So, other API will support?

Comment: Don't know Google is your friend